# Square root of a number modulo $p$ where $p\equiv3\bmod4$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

I know that for $a\in\Bbb N$ and $p$ prime, where $p\nmid a$, if $p\equiv3\bmod4$ we can solve $x^2\equiv a\bmod p$ easily with the equation
$$x=\pm a^{(p+1)/4}$$
I tried this with $a=6$ and $p=23$ and got the an answer of 12, which is correct, but 11 is also supposed to be a square root of $6\bmod23$. Is this a contradiction? Why didn't the formula work?

Comment: 11 = -12 mod 23.  No problem.

Comment: x=+/- 6^6.  6^2=13,6^3=78=9,6^6=81=12.  So x=+/- 12.  -12 = 11.  So all is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$11\equiv-12\bmod23$$
and that if $x^2\equiv a\bmod p$ then $(-x)^2\equiv a\bmod p$.

Basic algebraic manipulations work much the same way in modular arithmetic as they do in ordinary arithmetic.

Comment: Oh wow can't believe I missed that!